# Studying flask mega-tutorial appears an issue. From flask_wtf import FlaskForm error

Tags: python, api, flask, pycharm, flask-wtforms

I investigate Flask framework and have met the issue. I use PyCharm and when i import FlaskForm from flask_wtf appears 'Unresolved reference' error.

I tryed to install flask_wtf in environment and beyond. But issue didn't resolve.

Comment: Which version of flask_wtf do you have?

Comment: I have flask-wtf 1.1.1. I have resolved this issue by installing flask-wtf in PyCharm.